# Is "in addition" a sentence connector or a conjunction

Tags: parts-of-speech

> "The weather here is terrible. In spite of heavy rain, we've had gale force winds.
> Until the bad weather, we're doing a lot of walking.Yesterday was typical.
> When we got up it was wet — of course — and we decided to wait until
> the rain stopped. The sun came out by midday and we set off for Wicklow Hill. We had hardly started to climb when it began pouring down! ......,
> the wind was so strong, we were almost blown over. But we still got to the top!"

So here can you use in addition? There's a comma, that's why I'm asking whether it's a sentence connector, since then I could use it. Or can it be both of them in different cases?

Answer (score 1):

"In addition" is a prepositional phrase.  It can be used at the start of a sentence to link it with the previous sentence.  It would be normal to use a comma to separate an initial prepositional phrase (or other adverbial) from the subject of the sentence (and in speech intonate accordingly). There are plenty of other options, adverbs such as "Moreover" or "Also". Or you can put something more meaningful, like "unfortunately" or "When we reached the north ridge"

Conjunctions are single words, like "and" or "but".